# Protecting web-server from ssh brute force attacks

Tags: security, ssh, webserver

I have a server acting as a reverse-proxy connected directly to the internet.  I access this computer through ssh on a non-standard port.  It doesn't seem too secure.  If someone found the ssh port they could brute-force it and gain access to the computer.

Is there a more secure way to configure this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend a tool like [denyhosts](http://denyhosts.sourceforge.net/) or [sshguard](http://www.sshguard.net/), which watch your logs for failed logins, and auto ban IPs based on the rules you set.

Comment: Also consider using [public key authentication](http://macnugget.org/projects/publickeys/) and disallowing password authentication.

Answer (score 2):

Brute forcing SSH is very slow and time consuming, by design.  With OpenSSH (most implementations are similar) there is a couple second delay after submitting an incorrect password.  After three failures the connection is dropped.  This makes it unbelievably slow to brute force a password of even moderate entropy.  Generally brute forcing of SSH is not a problem so long as your server doesn't have a ton of threads accepting connections and your passwords is sufficiently complex.

Nevertheless @demure's suggestion to use denyhosts or sshguard would not only put your mind at ease, but it would help you detect attacks and possibly take action if necessary.  @Steve's suggestion to use public key authentication is also an excellent preventive measure.  If you're truly paranoid, consider adding password and public key authentication to achieve [two-factor authentication.  Something you have and something you know.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-factor_authentication)

Answer (score 0):

I use fail2ban and wrote a utility myself in C# using mono to add any IP that comes to attack my SSHD to add them to the /etc/hosts.deny as well. Now I see there are some persistent hackers whose IP addresses are kept getting refused. They always come back the next day, though. Digital Ocean has a good tutorial for setting up fail2ban [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-protect-ssh-with-fail2ban-on-ubuntu-14-04).

Edit: I changed my logging from username password to Certificate based authentication and that seemed to have reduced most of the attacks but some people even use brute force to crack the certificate. I changed my code now based on the new logs. That seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Brute force SSH attacks that can suck the resources from a server. The problem can be especially exasperating on low powered servers with a minimal amount of processors (CPU) and memory (RAM).

We developed a solution that downloads IP address black lists of known SSH attackers and adds them to the `/etc/hosts.deny` file.

The solution is released as an open source project named [am-deny-hosts](https://github.com/Astromine/am-deny-hosts) on GitHub. The project consists of a set of shell scripts that does the job without taking up a lot of time, CPU, or memory.